# How to use AngularJS in script tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to use Angular with this Stripe payment modal.  None of the price variables are are being assigned in the script tag.  Is there some way to do this with Angular?

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" data-key="pk_test_" data-amount={{price}} data-name="Example Product" data-description="Example Product {{price}}" data-image="/128x128.png">
  </script>
   <br>Price ${{price}}
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Angular:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.price = "77";
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ppq1orso/

Comment: What is your problem exactly? I've run your fiddle and it works just fine... Look at the DOM tree screen: http://oi58.tinypic.com/23mph87.jpg

Comment: Interesting.  Why doesn't the jsfiddle do that?  I also tried this on a local file and it doesn't work either.  Can you post a jsfiddle with your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the properties in the controller instead of using the script tag

You´ll have to add a custom button

```
 <button type="submit" ng-click="pay()" class="stripe-button-el" style="visibility: visible;"><span style="display: block; min-height: 30px;">Pay with Card</span></button>
```

And in the controller:

```
 var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        image: "https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png",
        key:'pk_test_'
    });

    $scope.pay = function(){
        handler.open({
            name: 'Example Product',
            description: 'Example Product ' + $scope.price,
            amount: $scope.price * 100
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    };
```

This work as expected:

http://jsfiddle.net/ppq1orso/3/

Comment: Awesome!  This is completely different than any code examples Stripe offers.  One question: Is there a way to get the (more attractive) blue button look?  I'm guessing maybe it can be styled?

Comment: Yes. I edited the answer. I forgot to add the css reference on jsfiddle!

Comment: Thanks again.  If I use the latest google angular reference in my local file (//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js), the popup doesn't work.  But using 1.2.1 ((//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.js) does work.  Seems like the latest version would be best.  Do you know why the latest isn't working for this?

Comment: Here is working with 1.3.5: http://jsfiddle.net/ppq1orso/4/. I had to change the controller definition and removed the form (this is a jsfiddle issue). For your local environment, just change the controller code and test it

Comment: I just noticed another thing in the code that you solved for me.  If my product is $50, in the button of the stripe modal, it displays as .50.  You multiply by 100 to get around this.  I must have missed that in the stripe documentation.  How did you find out that multiplying by 100 is needed?

Comment: I saw it in the checkout documentation. Here is the example: the data-description is "2 widgets ($20.00)", but the amount is data-amount="2000". The except the decimal numbers too. https://stripe.com/docs/checkout

Comment: Thanks on the clarification.